# How to (completely) delete one of the version of Eclipse from Windows 10

Tags: eclipse, duplicates, windows-10

Couple of days ago, I've got  error

since the error message was too long, I decided maybe downloading a new version without deleting all  settings and files could be much faster; then I noticed it installs two Eclipse parallelly, and they don't interfere each other (at least at the surface), but I may have some issue in the long run, so I decided to remove the older version and keep the old one.

[image]

Now, I am looking the above two versions

they are not visible under: **Control Panel** --> **All Control Panel Items** --> **Programs and Features**

I can just delete from there, but all other hidden folders, paths, other finger-nails may stay in my PC.

what's the best way to delete the older version like it never happened before?

Thank you for your generous assistance on this!

Comment: It depends on how you installed it. Did you use the Eclipse Installer?

Comment: @howlger: Thanks for your response. I used <eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe> file to install it; but it seems like it does not leave a trail in the Control Panel like some software do.